# R9100 chainring and R8000 crankset

Tags: shimano, chainring, compatibility

Is there compatibility between R8000 crankset and R9100 chainring?

I would like to mount a 54 ring on an R8000 DI2 crankset.

Answer (score 4):

9100 Shimano chainrings will fit on all 4 bolt Dura Ace, Ultegra, 105 or Tiagra cranksets. It's only when fitting the older style chainrings (9000, 6800, 5800 or 4700) onto the new cranksets (9100, 8000, 7000) that you run into compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks mate. Am I going to face issue since I use 54 thoot instead of 53 with the di2 FD?

Comment: An Ultegra Di2 front derailleur will be able to handle a 54 tooth chainring. You may just need to move it up a little higher on the derailleur mount.